# Php errors on ec2 server that doesn't appear on my old server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, php-5.4

While moving my website from my old server to an ec2 micro instance I'm getting stack errors from php that didn't appear on my old server...I have checked my php version and it's the same on both (5.4.45).
Looking at my the ec2 instance log I get this error `unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)`

¿Do I'm missing anything on my conf to avoid this errors..?
I can upload the phpinfo details for both if required via image capture.

**OLD SERVER CONFIGURATION**
[image: OLD SERVER CONFIGURATION]

**EC2 INSTANCE CONFIGURATION**
[image: EC2 server configuration]

Comment: Could we see the code where the error is happening?

Comment: The strange thing is that this code works on another server...so that's why I'm thinking that perhaps is due to the configurations of the server...

Comment: Possibly. post the config's, and the code that is causing the error? It looks like it's a PHP parse error, somewhere just before the endforeach or on the endforeach line.

Answer (score -2):

Can you copy the code block that this error is referring to?
in particular the lines leading up to where the error is triggered

Comment: This isn't an answer - use comments.